How to make Ubuntu 22.04 resize all windows the same way
When I try to resize a window from the bottom right corner some windows, like Files, just resize from the bottom right corner. Some windows, like Files' Preferences, also resize from the top left at the same time.
New to Ubuntu. How do I stop the top left moving itself, to stop it being confusing?
